# R: subsetting based on overlap of multiple files

Tags: r

In R I want to do the following:

I have a gene.list with 5 dataframes, where each dataframe looks like this:

```
col1
name1
name2
name3
...
```

Firstly I want to extract the overlap of those five dataframes. The output has to be a new dataframe: output

I have another list, called coverage.list with 11 dataframes. Each dataframe looks like this

```
col1     col2    col3
name1-a  1       2
name2-c  3       4
name3-d  5       6
name4-e  7       8
```

Now from each dataframe in coverage.list, I want to extract the lines where the value in col1 starts with the a value present in the new output dataframe, created in the previous step. The output should be a new list called coverage.new.list

The first step: extracting the overlap of the 5 dataframes, I was trying to use

```
Reduce(intersect, coverage.list))
```

But I get as a message 'data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows'. However when I use the venn function on this list, I get the correct overlap counts

Could you point me to the correct solution?

Comment: Whant you say overlap, you mean rows with the same value? Your dataframe is really just one column?

Comment: indeed, rows with the same value. and indeed, all dataframes from list coverage.list are just one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Inner join on the gene.list tables. Inner join gene.list[[1]] with gene.list[[2]] then 
#  inner join the result with gene.list[[3]] then inner join
#  then inner join with gene.list[[4]] then with gene.list[[5]]

output <- inner_join(gene.list[[1]], gene.list[[2]]) %>% inner_join(gene.list[[3]]) %>% 
  inner_join(gene.list[[4]]) %>% inner_join(gene.list[[5]])

coverage.list.new <- lapply(coverage.list, function(x) {x %>% mutate(backup=col1) %>%
     separate(col1, c("col1", "col1_2"), sep="-") %>% filter(col1 %in% output$col1) %>%
     mutate(col1=backup) %>% select(-c(backup, col1_2))})
```

***Update***

```
coverage.list.new <- lapply(coverage.list, function(x) {x %>% 
     mutate(backup=col1, col1=sub("-", "@", col1)) %>%
     separate(col1, c("col1", "col1_2"), sep="@") %>% filter(col1 %in% output$col1) %>%
     mutate(col1=backup) %>% select(-c(backup, col1_2))})
# with col1=sub("-", "@", col1) in mutate i am substituting the first - with @ 
# in order to then split col1 by the @. If you have @ in your col1 to begin with 
# then choose a symbol that does not exist in your col1 and replace  
# in the code above the @ symbol with your chosen symbol.
```

***Sample Data***

```
gene.list <- list(data.frame(col1=c("name1", "name2", "name3")),
              data.frame(col1=c("name1", "name3", "name4")),
              data.frame(col1=c("name1", "name3", "name4")),
              data.frame(col1=c("name1", "name3", "name4")),
              data.frame(col1=c("name1", "name3", "name4")))

coverage.list <- list(data.frame(col1=c("name1-a", "name2-c", "name3-d", "name4-e"), 
                             col2=c(1, 3, 5, 7), col3=c(2, 4, 6, 8)),
                  data.frame(col1=c("name3-a", "name4-c", "name3-d", "name4-e"), 
                             col2=c(1, 3, 5, 7), col3=c(2, 4, 6, 8)))
```

Comment: Good question, i should have specified. There is a nice article here http://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/

Comment: backup=col1: is this col1 from coverage.list?

Comment: the `%>%` is called pipe or chain. in the code above this `inner_join(x, y) %>% inner_join(z)` is equivalent to `inner_join(inner_join(x, y), z)`

Comment: I will put some comments in the code to make it more readable. Does it do what you are looking for though?

Comment: the first part definitely works. However in the seconds part where I create the coverage.list.new, I get the following error: Error during wrapup: Values not split into 2 pieces at 1,2,3,4, and so on

Comment: Could you run just this in the 2nd part and let me know if you get the same error `lapply(coverage.list, function(x) {x %>% separate(col1, c("col1", "col1_2"))`

Comment: gives indeed the same error. the name1-a, name2-c, ... is somewhat different in my dataset. the 'a' and 'c' can be any string of any length. But there is always something after the "-"

Comment: ok Then this means that your `col1` in `coverage.list` are not all of the form `xyz-abc` meaning that they do not all have the `-` after `name.` you need to specify what other cases you have.

Comment: They are of this form: "BCS1L-NM_001257343". A string of any length, then "-", then "NM_" and then a number of any length. And it's the string of any length before the "-" that should match

Comment: Try the updated the my answer. I have added `, sep="-"` in the `separate` function. Read up on `tidyr` to figure out what is happening.

Comment: it's driving me crazy. First of all 'sep = "-"' didn't work because there are also some examples where there is an extra "-" in the first part like this: BC-S1L-NM_0012'. So then I tried to use "-NM" as sep, but still some lines throw an error, because there are some examples where I have "BCS1L-uce001'. So "-NM" is not an option. What to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76393/discussion-between-dimitris-ps-and-user1987607).